# Tableau + Vertica 6 - How to connect Tableau to Vertica 6 on a Windows Server Machine

Tags: windows, odbc, vertica

I am trying to connect Tableau 9.0.2 running on a Windows Server Machine (2008 R2 Standard) to HP Vertica 6.X.

I found ODBC drivers for version 7, but have had no luck with version 6.1.3.

Can anyone help?

Note - I have Tableau Desktop running on my Mac and I am able to connect to Vertica with ODBC driver 6.1.3 installed on my MAC.

Is there a similar driver for Windows Server?

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Reach out to Vertica support to get the appropriate drivers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work for the Partner Engineering team at Vertica and I am happy to help you with your question. To connect to Vertica 6.x using Tableau on Windows you need to download and install the Vertica client package 6.x for windows. To download version 6.x of the Vertica client for Windows, please sign up to https://my.vertica.com/. If you sign up as a customer your account should have the permissions to download all previous versions of the driver. The drivers are available on the downloads page and on the right hand side of the screen under "Other Vertica Versions". 
For detail information about connectivity check out the connection guide: https://community.dev.hp.com/eidsp57264/attachments/eidsp57264/bigdata_wiki_vertica/19/2/HP_Vertica_Tableau_Connection_Guide.pdf
I hope this information is helpful,

Norma

Answer (score 1):

we have a connectivity video: https://community.dev.hp.com/t5/Vertica-Blog/Tableau-Desktop-9-x-with-HP-Vertica/ba-p/230251
and also, our community forums are a great resource: https://community.dev.hp.com/t5/Vertica-Forum/bd-p/bigdata_forums_vertica